# Is this package missing and if so, how do I fix?

Tags: oracle, datapump

I am following the given link.
https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/oracle-data-pump-10g

I'm an Oracle newbie. Oracle 12c is the target version. I have a Development database running in a docker image and I'm logged in as `sys` user to make sure that I can see everything. I'm using DataGrip as a client. I'm looking for the `DBMS_DATAPUMP` package but I don't see it in the GUI and I've also tried `SELECT * FROM ALL_OBJECTS WHERE OBJECT_TYPE IN ('FUNCTION','PROCEDURE','package') order by OBJECT_NAME;`, but I still don't see it. If it isn't installed, where do I download it from? I believe I've already figured out how to install it.

Our objective is as follows. We want to try creating a master schema in CI that is kept up to date on a weekly or monthly basis and then we want to copy that schema as our starting point for integration tests. Right now we are suffering through a painfully long flyway based migration process.

Comment: The name of the package is `DBMS_DATAPUMP`, not `DATA_PUMP`.

Comment: To your last edit: strings are case sensitive, the value of `OBJECT_TYPE` is `PACKAGE`, not `package`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Data Pump is a fully integrated feature of Oracle Database 11g. Data
>   Pump is installed automatically during database creation and database
>   upgrade...[more](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/datapump-faq-082259.html)

It should be installed during the database creation. I found logical error in your query to check whether or not the data pump package is installed. The object type `PACKAGE` should be in upper case to be selected.

Demo:

You query has returned the following only.

```
SQL> SELECT object_name FROM ALL_OBJECTS WHERE OBJECT_TYPE IN ('FUNCTION','PROCEDURE','package') and object_name like '%DATA%' order by OBJECT_NAME;

OBJECT_NAME
------------------------------
DATABASE_NAME
DBMS_FEATURE_DATABASE_VAULT
DBMS_FEATURE_DATA_GUARD
DBMS_FEATURE_DATA_REDACTION
DBMS_FEATURE_EXADATA
EXF$VALIDATEDATAITEM
ODCIANYDATADUMP
XDB_DATASTORE_PROC

8 rows selected.
```

And the query with object type `PACKAGE` in upper case has returned the following. You can see the `DATAPUMP` package is there.

```
SQL> SELECT object_name FROM ALL_OBJECTS WHERE OBJECT_TYPE IN ('FUNCTION','PROCEDURE','PACKAGE') and object_name like '%DATA%' order by OBJECT_NAME;

OBJECT_NAME
------------------------------
...
CWM1_OLAP_VALIDATE_METADATA
CWM2_OLAP_METADATA_REFRESH
CWM2_OLAP_VALIDATE_METADATA
DATABASE_NAME
DBMS_DATAPUMP
DBMS_DATAPUMP_UTL
DBMS_DATA_MINING
DBMS_DATA_MINING_INTERNAL
...
```