# How do I copy a schema for an instance of Oracle running in a Docker container?

Tags: oracle, schema, copy

Pursuant to this question: 
[Is this package missing and if so, how do I fix?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/147541/is-this-package-missing-and-if-so-how-do-i-fix)

...now I actually want to perform the copy of a schema using this package. ...except I can't figure out how to do that. I've seen this: [How to create copy of full schema on same database in oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26785645/how-to-create-copy-of-full-schema-on-same-database-in-oracle) but I can't seem to execute the commands. As mentioned in the previous question, we are running Oracle in a docker container, so this might be complicating matters. Again, I'm using DataGrip to connect. Since it's in a container, all of our connections are from remote. ...am I going to have to get into the container somehow? Docker is also something that is outside of my expertise.

I've tried executing:

```
expdp fromUser/fromPword schemas=sourceSchema directory=DUMPDIR dumpfile=dump.dmp logfile=explog.txt
```

...as well as...

```
exec expdp fromUser/fromPword schemas=sourceSchema directory=DUMPDIR dumpfile=dump.dmp logfile=explog.txt
```

I've also created the directory object DUMPDIR and granted read/write to it.

Comment: what error message are you getting? Note that expdp is a command line client. You run it on the host OS.

Comment: OK then that is probably the problem. I didn't know you could execute stored procedures from CLI. ...or is it possible that an Oracle package might contain more that Stored Procedures?

Comment: expdp is not a stored procedure. It probably uses some stored procedures to execute its tasks, but it's a command line client.

Comment: Understood but this seems odd to me because it's part of the DBMS_DATAPUMP package according to the docs.

Comment: I think you need to read those docs more carefully

Comment: anyway I'll make that comment an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

expdp is a command line utility that interacts with the DBMS_DATAPUMP API. You run it on the host OS, not from within another client.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_datpmp.htm#BABHBEHH

> See Also:
>   Oracle Database Utilities for more information on the concepts behind the DBMS_DATAPUMP API, how it works, and how it is implemented in the Data Pump Export and Import utilities

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/dp_overview.htm#i1009203